# Sorting an array by multiple fields

Tags: php, arrays, array-multisort

In my backend I have some code handling teams for a round robin group tournament, and in the end teams are returned in an array and contains match results/stats etc.

I have the following array which I want to sort by two fields in the following order: `points` (desc), `round_difference` (desc).

The final and correct order would be: `TeamOne`, `TeamThree`, `TeamTwo`.

How would I go on about this with an array in this format? Is it possible at all? I have looked into `array_multisort()` however my array keys/structure overall is a bit *"odd"* compared to the other code examples I found here on the page and was very confusing to me.

Hopefully someone can assist me in this.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [group] => 1
                    [name] => TeamOne
                    [tag] => One
                    [matches] => Array
                        (
                            [played] => 1
                            [won] => 0
                            [ot_won] => 1
                            [ot_lost] => 0
                            [lost] => 0
                            [round_difference] => 3
                            [points] => 2
                        )

                )

            [238] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 238
                    [group] => 1
                    [name] => TeamTwo
                    [tag] => Two
                    [matches] => Array
                        (
                            [played] => 0
                            [won] => 0
                            [ot_won] => 0
                            [ot_lost] => 0
                            [lost] => 0
                            [round_difference] => 0
                            [points] => 0
                        )

                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 14
                    [group] => 1
                    [name] => TeamThree
                    [tag] => Three
                    [matches] => Array
                        (
                            [played] => 1
                            [won] => 0
                            [ot_won] => 0
                            [ot_lost] => 1
                            [lost] => 0
                            [round_difference] => -3
                            [points] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
```

Comment: Are each team always inside key `1`? For example, `$records = array(1 => array( team1_array, team2_array, team3_array) )`?

Comment: The key `1` is basically an indicator for the group number. I know the structure is odd and can definitely be changed, but if a solution can be made with this structure without changing it, it would be great. So there will be a key number `2` + `3` etc. depending on how many groups there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `uasort()` instead and compare the keys like so:

```
uasort($arr[1],function($a,$b){
    # If the points are more/less right off the bat, return results
    if($a['matches']['points'] < $b['matches']['points'])
        return true;
    # If they are the same
    elseif($a['matches']['points'] == $b['matches']['points'])
        # Compare round_difference sort by that
        return ($a['matches']['round_difference'] < $b['matches']['round_difference']);
});
```

So, sorting something like this:

```
$arr    =   array(
    1 => array(
        1 => array(
                'id' => 1,
                'group' => 1,
                'name' => 'TeamOne',
                'tag' => 'One',
                'matches' => array(
                        'played' => 1,
                        'won' => 0,
                        'ot_won' => 1,
                        'ot_lost' => 0,
                        'lost' => 0,
                        'round_difference' => 3,
                        'points' => 2
                    )

            ),
        238 => array
            (
                'id' => 238,
                'group' => 1,
                'name' => 'TeamTwo',
                'tag' => 'Two',
                'matches' => array(
                        'played' => 0,
                        'won' => 0,
                        'ot_won' => 0,
                        'ot_lost' => 0,
                        'lost' => 0,
                        'round_difference' => 0,
                        'points' => 0,
                    )

            ),
        14 => array
            (
                'id' => 14,
                'group' => 1,
                'name' => 'TeamThree',
                'tag' => 'Three',
                'matches' => array
                    (
                        'played' => 1,
                        'won' => 0,
                        'ot_won' => 0,
                        'ot_lost' => 1,
                        'lost' => 0,
                        'round_difference' => '-3',
                        'points' => 1,
                    )

            ),
        17 => array
            (
                'id' => 17,
                'group' => 1,
                'name' => 'TeamFive',
                'tag' => 'Five',
                'matches' => array
                    (
                        'played' => 1,
                        'won' => 0,
                        'ot_won' => 0,
                        'ot_lost' => 1,
                        'lost' => 0,
                        'round_difference' => '-3',
                        'points' => 2,
                    )

            )
        )
    );
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [group] => 1
                    [name] => TeamOne
                    [tag] => One
                    [matches] => Array
                        (
                            [played] => 1
                            [won] => 0
                            [ot_won] => 1
                            [ot_lost] => 0
                            [lost] => 0
                            [round_difference] => 3
                            [points] => 2
                        )

                )

            [17] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17
                    [group] => 1
                    [name] => TeamFive
                    [tag] => Five
                    [matches] => Array
                        (
                            [played] => 1
                            [won] => 0
                            [ot_won] => 0
                            [ot_lost] => 1
                            [lost] => 0
                            [round_difference] => -3
                            [points] => 2
                        )

                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 14
                    [group] => 1
                    [name] => TeamThree
                    [tag] => Three
                    [matches] => Array
                        (
                            [played] => 1
                            [won] => 0
                            [ot_won] => 0
                            [ot_lost] => 1
                            [lost] => 0
                            [round_difference] => -3
                            [points] => 1
                        )

                )

            [238] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 238
                    [group] => 1
                    [name] => TeamTwo
                    [tag] => Two
                    [matches] => Array
                        (
                            [played] => 0
                            [won] => 0
                            [ot_won] => 0
                            [ot_lost] => 0
                            [lost] => 0
                            [round_difference] => 0
                            [points] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: **Anonymous downvoter:** An explanation on the downvote would be appreciated. Is the downvote to indicate a dispute that it works as I have described or that perhaps it may work only in this limited scope? Serves no purpose to downvote without stating a reason unless the reason is obvious or meant to antagonize.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I am looking for. Had to put it in a foreach loop to support multiple "groups" (the first key), but it works as intended. Is this function in any way heavy to use in the bigger image? And I'm curious of the random downvote too...

Comment: A foreach loop is fine. Most native php functions are pretty speedy so I wouldn't worry about speed unless you see it's really bogging down, but I doubt you'll have any speed issues.